# Magento "Reset Filter" in admin grid not working in "Bundle Items" and "Associated Products" tabs

Tags: admin, grid, bundled-product, grouped-products, reset-filter

I am working on Magento ver. ce-1.9.1.0 and I have made some major customizations in Product's custom options Block file and also created couple of custom product types based on Simple product type.

The issue I encounter now is whenever I create a "Bundle Product" & "Grouped Product" in admin and then if I go to "Bundle Items" tab or "Associated Products" tab respectively and press "Reset Filter" button then it shows "No records found", eventhough, I have created one simple product and it is working in frontend.

Could this be due to custom product types I have created, though I have disabled the module and checked but still same erroroneous situation.
The "Reset Filter" function for "Related", "Upsell" & "Cross-sell" product tabs is working fine.

Need some guidance as to how "Reset Filter" fetches simple products list for "Bundle" & "Grouped" products & what could be triggering the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product types that are allowed in bundle products are defined via config XML.

By default this is:

```
<allowed_selection_types>
    <simple/>
    <virtual/>
</allowed_selection_types>
```

See: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/etc/config.xml#L103-L106

Please use `var_dump(Mage::helper('bundle')->getAllowedSelectionTypes());` to see if the used value actually contains "simple". I suspect that you somehow changed that with your custom product types.

Comment: Thanks a ton, worked for me like a charm!!! +1 for this answer so it can help everyone.